# Как остановить или перезапустить цикл? Или каким другим циклом пользоваться в данном случае?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

В массиве keyLvl есть значения 22, 60, 100 и тд. Сейчас currenLevel 60, поэтому при первом срабатывании цикла i == 22; поэтому сразу срабатывает Else, а мне надо, чтобы сначала проверил все элементы массива и если не совпало только тогда срабатывал Else. Как такое сделать, может поставить break, return где нибудь? KeyLvl это уровни, в которых нужно играть за ключи, а Else это обычный уровень.

```
for (int i = 0; i < collKeysArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (currentLevel == keyLvl[i]) //уровень с ключами. если уже собрал 3 ключа, то больше не прибавляется, если переиграть уровень.
                    {
                        if (collectedKeys < collKeysArray[i])
                        {
                            collectedKeys++;
                            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("keys", collectedKeys); //как только заработал ключ, сразу сохраняет локально
                            Timer.SetActive(true);
                            Timer.GetComponentInChildren<GateTimer>().SetTimer();

                            if (collectedKeys == collKeysArray[i]) //текущем уровне, победить можно, если собрать определенное количество ключей
                            {
                                Timer.GetComponentInChildren<GateTimer>().TimeIsUp();
                                OnMenuComplete();
                                if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt(string.Format("Level.{0:000}.StarsCount", currentLevel), 0) < stars)
                                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt(string.Format("Level.{0:000}.StarsCount", currentLevel), stars);
                                if (Score > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score" + currentLevel))
                                {
                                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score" + currentLevel, Score);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        OnMenuComplete();
                        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt(string.Format("Level.{0:000}.StarsCount", currentLevel), 0) < stars)
                            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(string.Format("Level.{0:000}.StarsCount", currentLevel), stars);
                        if (Score > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score" + currentLevel))
                        {
                            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score" + currentLevel, Score);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Можно обойтись без цикла, воспользовавшись LINQ. Либо ставьте в цикле флаг (например булевую переменную) и за циклом его проверяйте.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что у вас тут происходит :) для чего используется этот метод? что такое keyLvl, currentLevel и collKeysArray? Т.е. их суть, что вы в них храните и зачем проверяете?)

Comment: @M.Green вопрос не в этом, ну да ладно: keyLvl - это уровни, где надо играть за ключи, currentLevel - это текущий уровень (проверяю входит ли он в уровень с ключами или нет), collKeysArray - это массив с элементами 3, 6, 9  и тд (по 3 прибавляется), это сколько ключей надо собрать, чтобы пройти. Например: Уровень с индексом 0 в массиве KeyLvl надо собрать количество ключей с индексом 0 в colKeysArray, т.е. 3. И т.д. Ну я новичок, понятно что всё говнокод, но разобраться тоже надо, а то уже голова болит. Кстати вы мой лидер по ответам и любезности, потом агрессивый Riotbracket или как там xD

Comment: @PinPin, а не пробовали в цикле идти не из начала в конец, а из конца в начало?) for (int i =  collKeysArray.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)

Comment: @M.Green и тут я понял, что последний элемент как и первый не соответствует условию, т.е. одно и то же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть вот такой вариант. Статический класс Array предлагает некоторые удобные методы для работы с массивами, например `IndexOf` - этот метод вернёт вам индекс в массиве элемента, который вы ищите, если этого элемента там нет, то он вернёт -1.

У класса `List<T>` все эти методы реализованы напрямую.
Итак, что мы делаем - ищем в массиве ключевых уровней индекс текущего уровня. Если этот уровень не входит в массив, то нам возвращается -1 и мы показываем победную панель, если входит, то мы получаем из массива требуемых ключей по индексу уровня нужное на нём количество ключей.

Дальше делаем проверки и, либо открываем панель победы, либо заставляем играть опять, как я понял) ещё я вынес в отдельный метод дублирующийся код с сохранением результатов

```
void Methods()
{
    var index = Array.IndexOf(keyLvl, currentLevel);
    if (index != -1)
    {
        if (collectedKeys < collKeysArray[index])
        {
            collectedKeys++;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("keys", collectedKeys);
            Timer.SetActive(true);
            Timer.GetComponentInChildren<GateTimer>().SetTimer();
            if (collectedKeys == collKeysArray[i])
            {
                Timer.GetComponentInChildren<GateTimer>().TimeIsUp();
                CompleteMenu();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        CompleteMenu();
    }
}

void CompleteMenu()
{
    OnMenuComplete();
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt(string.Format("Level.{0:000}.StarsCount", currentLevel), 0) < stars)
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(string.Format("Level.{0:000}.StarsCount", currentLevel), stars);
    if (Score > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score" + currentLevel))
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score" + currentLevel, Score);
    }
}
```